# How was a factorial/gamma function obtained from solving this recurrence relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations

So I came up with the following recurrence relation for $m \geq 2$ and initial value $a_1 = 1$:
$$a_m = m+(m+1)a_{m-1}$$

Putting this result into Wolfram Alpha yields the following closed form:
$$a_m = \Gamma(m+2) - 1$$

I get how factorials/the gamma function might show up here, since for example, $a_5=5+6(4+5(3+4(2+(3*1))))$ which looks like a factorial would be involved. But I'm not sure how to go about solving it to get that explicit closed form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\;$ write it as $\,a_m+1=(m+1)(a_{m-1}+1)\,$ and telescope.

Answer (score 1):

Another, more general way.

Suppose
$a_m
=u_m+v_ma_{m-1}
$
with the
$u_m$ and $v_m$
known.

Let
$V_m=\prod_{k=1}^m v_k
$
so
$V_m
=v_mV_{m-1}
$
or
$\dfrac{v_m}{V_m}
=\dfrac1{V_{m-1}}
$.

Then,
dividing by $V_m$,

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{a_m}{V_m}
&=\dfrac{u_m}{V_m}+\dfrac{v_m}{V_m}a_{m-1}\\
&=\dfrac{u_m}{V_m}+\dfrac{a_{m-1}}{V_{m-1}}\\
\text{Let}\\
b_m
&=\dfrac{a_m}{V_m}\\
\text{and}\\
w_m
&=\dfrac{u_m}{V_m}\\
\text{Then}\\
b_m
&=w_m+b_{m-1}\\
\text{or}\\
w_m
&=b_m-b_{m-1}\\
\text{Summing,}\\
b_M-b_2
&=\sum_{m=2}^M (b_m-b_{m-1})\\
&=\sum_{m=2}^M w_m\\
\text{or}\\
b_M
&=b_2+\sum_{m=2}^M w_m\\
\text{or}\\
\dfrac{a_M}{V_M}
&=\dfrac{a_2}{V_2}+\sum_{m=2}^M w_m\\
\text{or}\\
a_M
&=\dfrac{a_2V_M}{V_2}+V_M\sum_{m=2}^M \dfrac{u_m}{V_m}\\
&=a_2\prod_{k=3}^M v_k+\sum_{m=2}^M u_m\prod_{k=m+1}v_k\\
\end{array}
$

If $v_k=k+1$
then
$V_m=(m+1)!$
and this is where the
factorial comes from.